# Executable file named 'test' is in $PATH but won't run

Tags: bash, shell-script, path, executable, strace

I have a file in $HOME/bin (before you ask, yes, it is in my path) called `test` which I've confirmed can be executed fine when I run it with the full path to the file. However, I get a really weird issue when I don't run it this way. When I just run `test` in the terminal, it doesn't do anything and returns immediately. I know that this isn't an issue of finding the file for several reasons:

1. There is no error message. Normally if the file can't be found or can't be executed a message will be printed out saying so.
2. Running `which test` still returns the correct file path.
3. Probably the weirdest of all - the script works fine when run through `strace`. I tried using `strace` to see if I could figure out what was going on but when I ran it with `strace`, it worked as expected with 0 issues.

Comment: Use `type`, not `which`. See [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/117037)

Comment: First tip at https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/debuggingtips

Answer (score 45):

`test` is an unfortunate name to use, it's the [standard utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/test.html) for conditional *tests*. (It's actually the same command as the `[` in `if [ ... ]`, it just *looks* like a syntactical thing, but is really just a normal command.)

`test` is also builtin in e.g. Bash, so running just `test` never looks up your binary from the path.

```
bash$ help test | head
test: test [expr]
    Evaluate conditional expression.

    Exits with a status of 0 (true) or 1 (false) depending on
    the evaluation of EXPR.  Expressions may be unary or binary.  
    [...]
```

`test` with no arguments just returns 1 (false).

Running `strace test` doesn't involve the shell builtin, since `strace` doesn't implement any utilities itself. It just uses what it finds in your `PATH`. Note that you probably have the standard `test` in `/bin/test` or `/usr/bin/test`, so if that would be first in `PATH`, `strace` would run run that.

On my Bash, `which` is also an external command, so it doesn't have an idea about builtins either. On the other hand, [the `type` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/type.html) is builtin to the shell, and `type test` would show that `test is a shell builtin`.

See also: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: [Have an anecdote from 1985](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/net.unix-wizards/geTFOFt4a9Y/BTnSRgX1E5AJ).